# Keeping PHPStorm files in sync with the ones generated on the server via php artisan

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, sftp, laravel-artisan

I am using Laravel with PHPStorm and a custom server where I connect via SFTP. The problem is that being SFTP, it's not in sync. So everytime I generate files via `php artisan` command, I have to download the file(s) with PHPStorm. I know that I can get around that by using Homestead and Shared folders, but this project requires a custom VPS.

I know that no SFTP "drive" is currently working ok with Windows. Also, the server is remote, not on the same network, so Samba can't do the job.

Thank you!

Comment: `Deployment | Sync with deployed...` ? Only that (safe) way. Anything like "remote drive" where you mount remote location into local file system / local drive will be slow ( such setup is not officially supported; IDE requires fast access to source files and you will see random freezes out of nowhere if working with files directly over network).

Comment: That would do, but I am trying to save some time and have the comfort to see the new files appear in the IDE automatically (just like them being on the local machine).

Comment: 1) This IDE is built using "local source has priority over remote" sort of approach. Deployment can be done automatically to remote only and not other way around (i.e. it cannot see new files on remote and download them into local machine automatically). 2) Even if you use "remote drive" .. the file system watchers to not always (almost never) work in such case -- looking for changes in file system (new/modified/deleted files) is expensive operation when working with remote stuff -- requires MUCH more time as compared to local file system (and I'm talking about your OS functionality here)

Comment: *"I know that I can get around that by using Homestead and Shared folders, but this project requires a custom VPS"* Why such special requirements? Why don't you make your own local custom VPS if it needs to be that way? Not ready-made Vagrant images .. but actual raw VirtualBox/VMWare Workstation/etc and install & configure OS from scratch; all done locally. Surely, you can try that "remote drive" approach .. but I'm telling you -- it will not be pleasant experience.

Comment: So the only alternative I may offer you here is to set up and run 3rd party sync tool (whatever will work for you; e.g. rsync) that will do such job for you -- will keep in sync local and remote location. This way you do not use deployment functionality from IDE at all. You can run such tool on your computer .. or try other way around -- share your local folder; mount it on remote VPS and run sync tool there.

Comment: Good idea to use VirtualBox and Shared folders. It looks like I will have more control that way and can simulate that VPS with ease. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a workflow I use, you may simply need to do the following, assuming you have already setup a default deployment server.

#### Editing remote files

If you are editing the remote files instead of a local copy, **don't**; instead:

- create a local copy/`git clone`/etc of you project files.
- create a new phpstorm project with the local copy.

#### Setting up a sync

If you already are working off a local copy but just need sync setup:

- `ctrl+shift+a`
- type `deployment`
- select `options`
- change the option: `Upload changed files automatically [..]` to `always`
- enable `upload external changes`

As an added bonus, this also automatically syncs assets from say `gulp watch` too.

---

#### If you haven't setup a deployment server

- `ctrl+shift+a`
- type `deployment`
- select `configuration`
- create a new server with you method of connection to it.
- enable as default server (last icon on the top left column)

**Important**: if you don't select the server as the default, it will not be able to auto upload changes.

Also don't forget to setup the excludes in the configuration menu, I usually exclude `bower_components`, and `node_modules` from deploying to my servers, and only send the build assets. (But it's up to you)

**EDIT:** Don't run commands remotely, run them locally and let them sync back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I execute the artisan commands on both sides... i do it on this way on my linux maschine

```
<?php
unset($argv[0]);
$params = implode(' ', $argv);
$remoteOutput = shell_exec("sshpass -p password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@1.1.1.1 'php /path/to/artisan $params'");
if(!empty($remoteOutput)){
    shell_exec("php artisan $params");
}
```

Save it and add it as commandline tool in phpstorm.... in windows i think you can use the PHP SSH library or somthing else.